# When I select App Scripts from the Google Sheets Extensions menu, I get a generic error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to try using scripts in Google Sheets, but I can't even get the App Scripts interface to open. As soon as I click on App Scripts in the Extensions menu of my sheet, I get a non-descriptive error (just says "Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes."), and I get this error no matter how long I wait to refresh.

I was expecting to run through these instructions:

https://spreadsheetpoint.com/multiple-selection-drop-down-google-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are using another account in sheet, for example your main account is "User A" and you are logging into Google Apps Script with "User B", if this is the case and you want to use "User B" in GAS, you must log out of your other account.